# qmake syntax error near unexpected token newline

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qt-creator, msys

I'm following the qmake example on page 40 (Rapid Dialog Design) of C++ GUI programming with qt 4 (2nd ed) by Blanchette and Summerfield.

I installed the make tools from http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS

I'm running **qt 5.5.1 on a 64-bit Windows 10. VS 2013 is installed.**

After running `qmake -project` and `qmake gotocell.pro` as in the instructions, I got this error:

```
   C:\Users\John\Documents\gotocell>make.exe
    make.exe -f Makefile.Release
    make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/John/Documents/gotocell'
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -O2 -MD -Zc:strictStrings -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I. -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Irelease -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013  -Forelease\ @<<
    /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
    /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -O2 -MD -Zc:strictStrings -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I. -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Irelease -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013  -Forelease\ @<<'
    make.exe[1]: *** [{.}.cpp{release\}.obj] Error 2
    make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/John/Documents/gotocell'
```

What's going on and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that qmake will generate an makefile that is compatible with nmake, not gnu make.

Try running nmake instead.

-Brad

Comment: How do I install nmake?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that problem is related to the `@<<` on the line.  After a `<<` on the shell command line, you should have a word, defining the end of input string of the following “HERE-document”.

Comment: @user3918985 Sorry, but I never used VS's `make` utility.  I don't know if that `@<<` is something that should have been interpreted by `make`, the `qmake` utility or even the Windows' default shell.  What surprises me a bit is that `make` is using Unix-like `/bin/sh` instead of Windows' `cmd.exe`.  In that case, I advise that you take care not only with `<<`, but also with other characters that might be special to `sh` but not to `cmd.exe`, such as “>”, “!”, “$”, “\”, “`”, parentheses, among others.